# To Display data from text file to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, nullpointerexception, abstracttablemodel

My Text file contain data as: sample.txt
      MEMHEAD 1 1 NA SetString srcCode

MEMHEAD 1 2 NA SetString memIdnum

LGLNAME 1 5 NA SetString onmfirst

I have created `MyClassModel` class extending `AbstractTableModel` as:

```
    public class MyClassModel extends AbstractTableModel 
{

    Vector data;
    Vector columns;
    public MyTableModel() {
            String line;

            try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sample.txt");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), ",");
                    while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
                           columns.addElement(st1.nextToken());
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                            while (st2.hasMoreTokens())
                                    data.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                    }
                    br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size() / getColumnCount();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return (String) data.elementAt((rowIndex * getColumnCount())
                            + columnIndex);
    }
}
}
```

In this way I retrieved data from a file. Now when I make a `JTable` and set model using `table.setModel(MyTableModel)`. I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

CONTINUED:

The text file data is being displayed in the JTable but JTable also contains some extra rows with some junk data and when I press on those rows
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 180 >= 180` this exception is thrown. 
However, I Found out that there is some problem with the line

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return (String) data.elementAt((rowIndex * getColumnCount()) + columnIndex);
}
```

But dont know what is the problem.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding data to both `Vectors` with out initializing them.

```
Vector data;
Vector columns;
```

Initialize them before you add elements.

```
Vector data = new Vector();
Vector columns = new Vector();
```

Check after doing this whether you are getting [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) or not.

If still you are getting `NPE` then I doubt that you didn't initialize `JTable`. So post code to make us know where exactly exception is coming.

Comment: @mKorbel    haha. Thanks for remembering me. I am having very tight schedule all these days so I am just asking questions to solve my issues. But now I got adjusted to this environment. Now I am happy but still working hard.

Answer (score 0):

The data from text file can be added to JTable using DefaultTableModel also. this is the simple and efficient way of doing this.

```
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sample.config");
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        DefaultTableModel dtm= new DefaultTableModel(0,6);  
    // (for each line in file)
    while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) 
          {
    dtm.addRow(line.split(" ")); 
     }
    br.close();
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[] { "Attribute"," #","Position",         "Transformation","Assignment","Field","Constant" });
```